# Comparing value of array in Mustache block loop

Tags: ruby, arrays, sinatra, mustache

So I am trying to render a select drop-down from an array using Mustache and Sinatra. The template code currently looks like this:

```
<select id="phone_prefix" name="phone_prefix">
    {{#prefixes}}
        <option value="{{to_s}}" {{selected}}>{{to_s}}</option>
    {{/prefixes}}
</select>
```

With the following method in the view it is rendering each item of the array:

```
def prefixes
  ["03", "04", "06", "07", "09", "021", "022", "025", "027", "028", "029"]
end
```

For the `{{selected}}` value in the mustache template I need to do a comparison on the array item currently being iterated over and a query string value coming in via `params[:phone_prefix]` which for instance is `"09"`. Then when there is a match return a value of `"selected"` to a `selected` method to pass to mustache.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push the logic into your Ruby and just feed data to Mustache. Update your `prefixes` method to return an Array of Hashes:

```
def prefixes
  # figure out which one is selected by asking params...
  [ { :n => '03', :selected => false }, { :n => '04', :selected => true }, ... ]
end
```

and then something like this in your template:

```
<select id="phone_prefix" name="phone_prefix">
    {{#prefixes}}
        <option value="{{n}}" {{#selected}}selected="selected"{{/selected}}>{{n}}</option>
    {{/prefixes}}
</select>
```

I've only used Mustache in JavaScript so I might be missing something in the Ruby flavor but something close to that should work, you just have to get information from `params` into your `prefixes` method.

Mustache is intentionally minimalistic and free of logic, [it even says so on the homepage](http://mustache.github.com/):

> Logic-less templates.

So all your logic goes in your code and you just set a bunch of variables and flags for Mustache to do things with. The only logic available in the template is "is this thing true?" and "can I iterate over this thing?"; anything more complicated than that has to go in the code that is preparing data for Mustache.

Answer (score 0):

Rad! Thanks! That worked a treat. I ended up with the following method for prefixes and it works great:

```
def prefixes
  prefix_list = [{:n => "03", :selected => false}, {:n => "04", :selected => false}, {:n => "06", :selected => false}, {:n => "07", :selected => false}, {:n => "09", :selected => false}, {:n => "021", :selected => false}, {:n => "022", :selected => false}, {:n => "025", :selected => false}, {:n => "027", :selected => false}, {:n => "028", :selected => false}, {:n => "029", :selected => false}]
  prefix_list.each do |i|
    if i[:n] == "09"
      i[:selected] = true
    end
  end
  prefix_list
end
```